# Pattern for conversion of a list of values between different 'types'

Tags: design-patterns

I'm making a program which will be able to convert between certain types of data (coordinate points). I user inputs the type of the data they are entering, the type of the data they want and the list of points.  So, I have to iterate over the list to parse and validate the data. Then make the proper conversions.

At the moment I have 4 possible accepted types (more may be added in the future), every type of coordinate point has its representing class but not every class can convert to another, sometimes additional things are needed to be done.  Also, any datum may be converted to any of the other types.

Currently, I just had a bunch of conditional statements to achieve, parsing, validation and conversion.  I want to implement this in a efficient and modular way that let me easily add more conversion types in the future. I just think that having a bunch of conditional statements its not a modular way, so I'm looking for a design pattern or way to organize my code such that it becomes easy to modify in the future.  Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). In a nutshell, you will have a common interface that many classes (one per data format) will implement. When the user selects one of the types, you can look it up (in a dictionary for instance) and instantiate the correct class to handle the data.

Comment: Thanks! That's the way I should be headed to